# Dialects in Grimm's Fairy Tales

Tags: dialect, history

I've been working my way through an 1890 copy of 'Kinder und Hausmärchen' by the brothers Grimm, and **several of them are in dialects about which I would love to know additional information, primarily name and associated region for the dialect**, based on the 5 samples of text I give below. History and culture associated with the tales would also be nice, as extras, but I'm mostly interested in the linguistic information.

## 19 Von dem Fischer un syner Fru

Der wöör maal eens en Fischer un syne Fru, de waanden tosamen in'n Pißputt, dicht an der See, un de Fischer güng alle Dage hen un angeld: un he angeld und angeld.

## 47 Von dem Machandelboom

Dat is nu all lang heer, wol twe dusend Johr, do wöör dar en ryk Mann, de hadd ene schöne frame Fru, un se hadden sik beyde sehr leef, hadden awerst kene Kinner, se wünschden sik awerst sehr welke, un de Fru hedd'd so veel dorüm Dag un Nacht, man se kregen keen un kregen keen.

## 82 De Spielhansl

Is is emohl e Mon gewön, der hot ninx us g'spielt, und do hobend'n d'Leut nur in Spielhansl g'hoaßen, und wal e gor nit afg'hört gen spieln, so hot e san Haus und ullss vespielt.

## 91 Dat Erdmänneken

Et was mal en rik Künig west, de hadde drei Döchter had, de wören alle Dage in den Schlottgoren spazeren gaen, un de Künig, dat was so en Leivhawer von allerhand wackeren Bömen west: un einen, den hadde he so leiv had, dat he denjenigen, de ümme en Appel dervon plückede, hunnerd Klaster unner de Eere verwünschede.

## 95 Der alte hildebrand

Es war amahl a Baur und a Bäurin, und dö Bäurin, dö hat der Pfarra im Dorf gern gesegn, un da hat er alleweil gwunschen, wann er nur amahl an ganzen Tag mit der Bäurin der wars halt a recht gwesn.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @Robert: *»... several of them are in dialects **about which I would love to know additional information** (origin of the dialect, history and culture associated with the tale, etcetera).«*

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ah, I see, thanks. I'd switch my close vote from "unclear" to "too broad" if that was possible.

Comment: E.g. *De Spielhansel* is a very old story. There are even versions where the *Hansel* may be identified with *Thor*.

Comment: @Robert OK, well, perhaps I was a little sloppy; I've edited the question, but jumping right to closure, my, my.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Thanks for clarifying on my behalf.

Comment: @Janka Interesting --

Comment: 19 is obviously a form of Platt (Low German), as seen by the usage of „he“. 49 is obviously from north of the Das/Dat Isogloss(https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dat-das-Linie)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will create an answer over the following days, salvaging Grimm‘s own comments. **This is ongoing work.** Two things are immediately obvious:

- 19 and 91 are some variants of Platt (Low German). Evidence is the usage of „he“.
- 47 and 91 are from north of the [Das Dat isogloss](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dat-das-Linie).

### Interpreting Grimm‘s comments on KHM (Kinder und Hausmärchen) 19 and 47-

We know one version of KHM 19 and 47 was ***pommerscher Mundart in Hamburg***, but the way I see it the complex editorial history forbids saying the same with certainty of the version here.

> Der Maler Philipp Otto Runge hat die Vorlage zu KHM 19 zugleich mit dem »Machandelboom« (KHM 47) in pommerscher Mundart in Hamburg aufgezeichnet und 1806 als Dank für den 1. Band von Des Knaben Wunderhorn an dessen Verleger Zimmer nach Heidelberg geschickt. Achim von Arnim machte diese Fassungen 1809 den Brüdern Grimm zugänglich. Eine divergierende Aufzeichnung Runges war auch an Johann Gustav Büsching gelangt, der diese noch vor den Grimms 1812 veröffentlichte ( Volks-Sagen , Märchen und Legenden , Leipzig 1812, Nr. 57). Wilhelm Grimm entschloss sich, durch diese textlichen Divergenzen und schlimmbessernde Eingriffe des aus Pommern stammenden Verlegers Reimer in den KHM-Druck irritiert, ab der 5. Auflage (1843) den (nach einem weiteren Manuskript Ph. O. Runges?) um beträchtliche Passagen erweiterten Text nach »Runge’s Werken« zu übernehmen ( Hinterlassene Schriften von Ph. O. Runge , hrsg. von dessen ältestem Bruder, Hamburg 1840, S. 430–435).

### Interpreting Grimm‘s comments on KHM 82.

In my view the relevant part of the comments is:

> Seit der Zweitauflage (1819) als Nr. 82 anstelle des Märchens »Die drei Schwestern« (Anh. Nr. 16); die Vorlage vermittelte Simon Sechter »aus Weitra« im Waldviertel (***Niederösterreich***).

This agrees with my limited experience of Lower Austrian Dialect. Hoping for confirmation by @Hubert Schölnast.

### Interpreting Grimm‘s comments on KHM 91

As said, this is Platt. For its localisation See Grimm‘s comments:

> Seit der Erstauflage (II, 1815, Nr. 5) an dieser Stelle, nach einer Einsendung der Ludowine von Haxthausen »***aus dem Paderbörnischen«*** vom Mai 1814;

### Interpreting Grimm‘s comments on KHM 95:

**Very Unclear, educated guess upper Austria. See below!**

> **die genauere Herkunft** dieses Textes »aus dem Österreichischen« (vielleicht aus dem heutigen Burgenland und durch Vermittlung Georg Passys?) **lässt sich nicht nachweisen**. Die Version »aus Deutschböhmen« dürfte Jacob Grimm 1815 in Wien bekannt geworden sein (vgl. Anm. zu KHM 82); die »Erzählung aus Hessen« (Anm. S. 173) kam vor 1822 zu, nähere Provenienz ist nicht ermittelt.

He is talking of three versions here. But my edition only contains one. Perhaps we are seeing the Austrian version here. The excerpts from KHM 95 below contain *ös*, *dö* and *gwunschen*. I found an [Austrian dialect with all three forms *ös*, *dö* and *gwunschen*](https://books.google.gr/books?id=vi4PAAAAIAAJ&pg=PT510&lpg=PT510&dq=gwunschen%20%C3%B6s&source=bl&ots=dePAIXYb8t&sig=NC2iZotEv68yJIKxRAkENMoKqtA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI-uD86uncAhVE6qQKHVPEBIcQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=gwunschen%20%C3%B6s&f=false) .It is from the part of Austria  formerly known as *[Österreich ob der Enns](http://www.ooegeschichte.at/themen/wir-oberoesterreicher/wir-oberoesterreicher/der-name-oberoesterreich.html)*, which I believe is an older term for upper Austria.

Excerpts from KHM 95

> Es war amahl a Baur und a Bäurin, und **dö** Bäurin, **dö** hat der Pfarra im Dorf gern gesegn, und da hat er alleweil **gwunschen**, wann er nur amahl an ganzen Tag mit der Bäurin allan recht vergnügt zubringa kunnt, und der Bäurin der war’s halt a recht gwesn.
>
> Der Pfarra aber und d’ Bäurin **dö** warn halt recht lusti. Endli fangt der Pfarra an und sagt »hanz, mein liebi Bäurin, **ös** könnt’s ja so schön singa, singt’s mir do ans.« »Ah« sagt die Bäurin, »hietzt kann i nix mehr singa, ja in mein junge Jahren, da hab i’s wohl könna, aber hietzt is schon vorbei.« »Ei«, sagt wieder der Pfarra, »singt’s do nur a bissl.« No, da fangt die Bäurin an und singt »I hab mein Mon wohl ausgesandt auf’m Göckerliberg in Wälischland.«

**Hoping for input from Switzerland and Austria!**

Comment: If you feel you need input from Switzerland an Austria for elaborating your so far excellent answer consider to make it CW (which is probably the appropriate way to go for such questions)

Comment: 95: Could the term »alleweil« be used to further narrow it down? I’m not sure in which dialects it appears, but it definitely is very common in Swabian (but could possibly be found in many dialects belonging to the groups *oberdeutsch* and *allemannisch*, I’m not sure).
Great answer!

Comment: @Philipp good idea. At the moment I am asking Austrian students. I got one reply from Steyr in Upper Austria saying it could be upper Austrian, possibly Salzkammergut. I provided a full page as a sample.

Comment: @Ludi I'm liking your answer very much -- please continue adding information as you like - but it has already provided just the sort of extra information I was after.

Comment: @Circulwyrd Rest assured that I will be trying to improve it for years if possible! I always do it. Sometimes I am worried people will interpret it as pushing my answers, but I am really passionate about continuously improving them!